# Looking for a calendar or date display app for iPhone

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, calendar

I am looking for a calendar app for the iPhone that simply displays the date and what day of the week it is in large letters.

And that's it. If there are extra bits of info such as sunrise and sundown that is ok, but I just need today's date (weekday and month) to be spelled out in large letters, to turn an unused iPhone into a wall clock for a senior person with dementia.

[Something like this](https://www.alzstore.com/robin-day-clock-with-reminders-p/0046.htm), but as an app or clean website.

Comment: the built-in calendar.app does that on its icon...

Comment: Definitely not “spelled out in large letters”

Comment: maybe [this](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/huge-digital-clock/id1515003825#?platform=iphone) is ok for you?

Comment: @Andra no because this is mainly a clock, it’s not possible to turn off time and just have the weekday and full date. Thanks though